# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$callback' on null object error Android Studio3.0 and app crashing

Tags: android, android-studio, crash

I have gone through all the solutions posted in stack related to this problem but none seems to work for me.Here is my code for my MainActivity:

```
package com.quizappproject.android.quizappproject;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

int score = 0;
TextView answerStatus = findViewById(R.id.answerStatus);
TextView scoreKeeper = findViewById(R.id.scoreKeeper);

public void checkAnswer(View view){
    CheckBox lionCheckBox = findViewById(R.id.lion);
    CheckBox rhinoCheckBox = findViewById(R.id.rhino);
    CheckBox leopardCheckBox = findViewById(R.id.leopard);

    if (lionCheckBox.isChecked() && rhinoCheckBox.isChecked() && leopardCheckBox.isChecked()) {
        score = score + 1;
        scoreKeeper.setText(String.valueOf(score));
        answerStatus.setText("CORRECT");
    }else{
        score = score + 0;
        scoreKeeper.setText(String.valueOf(score));
        answerStatus.setText("WRONG, TRY AGAIN");
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my logcat:

```
06-30 19:11:54.765 23172-23172/com.quizappproject.android.quizappproject E/ActivityThread: Exception when newActivity r=ActivityRecord{15ec5572 token=android.os.BinderProxy@1fd54dc3 {com.quizappproject.android.quizappproject/com.quizappproject.android.quizappproject.MainActivity}} token=android.os.BinderProxy@1fd54dc3
06-30 19:11:54.765 23172-23172/com.quizappproject.android.quizappproject D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
06-30 19:11:54.768 23172-23172/com.quizappproject.android.quizappproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.quizappproject.android.quizappproject, PID: 23172
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity  ComponentInfo{com.quizappproject.android.quizappproject/com.quizappproject.android.quizappproject.MainActivity}: 
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2457)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2632)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:183)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1485)
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5674)
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:963)
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:758)
                                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
                                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:117)
                                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:149)
                                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:56)
                                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:202)
                                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:183)
                                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:519)
                                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:190)
                                                                                           at com.quizappproject.android.quizappproject.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:18)
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                                           at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1606)
                                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1071)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2632) 
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:183) 
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1485) 
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5674) 
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:963) 
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:758)

06-30 19:11:54.770 880-1725/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity 1 com.quizappproject.android.quizappproject/.MainActivity
```

When I run my code on a real android device it crashes and I get the above error in my logcat. I disabled instant run in my settings but the app still crushes when I run it. What could be the problem with my code?

Comment: Put `findViewById()` statements in `onCreate()` method instead of outside it.

Comment: @Sanchita Santra but I need to use the textviews inside the checkAnswer method I created thats why the variables are global

Comment: The variables should be global. But keep the `findViewById()` calls inside `onCreate()`. Like - `TextView answerStatus;` outside. And `answerStatus = findViewById()` inside `onCreate()`.

Comment: @Sanchita Santra is it a must the findViewById() be called inside the onCreate or I can call it in any method

Comment: You can call it in any method which is called after `onCreate()`. Read up on Activity lifecycle - https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Comment: @Sachita Santra thanks it worked